# SQL Server : mapping values from one table to another

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on finger prints device reader in which the device (by itself) generates a sort of "keys" for each personnel. I take these keys and store them for each known employee I have in table `EmpInfo_Device` with two columns:

1. `DevKey` (which is the key generated by the FP reader)
2. `Emp_id` (which is a foreign key from another table `EmpInfo` for the specific employee in which the key is generated for)

(e.g. the device generated a key (40) for employee "Jack" with id (120)). sometimes there are certain individuals who are not employees but still use the device, thus generating a key for them. The problem is that I want to get all the log entries from another table `LogData_Stage1` which consists of several columns mainly:

1. DevKey (as mentioned before)
2. LogDateTime
3. LogType

Now, I want all the log entries from `LogData_Stage1` for the stored employees only in `EmpInfo_Device`.

I have tried this query but I feel it's somehow wrong.

```
Select *
From EmpInfo_Device e
Where e.DevKey in (Select lg.DevKey from LogData_Stage1 lg)
```

This query returns all the values in `EmpInfo_Device` - however, the number of distinct IDs in `LogData_Stage1` happens to be 86, so I'm a bit confused.

Thanks in advance and I'm sorry if the question was too long

Comment: Why do think that query is wrong?  It looks like it does what you want.

Comment: I need to Insert the values 'Emp_Id' (after getting it after mapping the Devkey w/ the query), 'LogDateTime', 'LogType' into another table in which I prevent the duplication of entry logs. I need a query that do that w/o having to get these 'Emp_id's alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this right, you want all the log entries, that were made for an employee (and not those for other, non employee users of the reader) along with the ID of the employees. For that, you can use an `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT ed.emp_id,
       l.logdatetime,
       l.logtype
       FROM logdata_stage1 l
            INNER JOIN empinfo_device ed
                       ON ed.devkey = l.devkey;
```

Comment: Thank you sir! That's pretty much what I needed